# Firebase onNewToken not refreshing my token

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

So, I need to refresh my token each time it expires, but the service runing behind ddoes not trigger `onNewToken()`

Manifest

```
 <service
            android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Code

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService: FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
        val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
        if(currentUser != null){
            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("user").document(currentUser).update("deviceToken",token)
        }
    }
}
```

Does I need to explicitly call `getInstanceID()` each time I go throught onStart() in my app ? or should this service update my deviceToken with the new one like I did ?

I have tested it with an old logged in account but notifications did not arrived, hence, the new token has not been refreshed (I needed to logout and login again to receive notifications once more)

Comment: how do you know that the token expires? Usually the tokens do not expire. To be safe that you do not miss a change as your service was not successfully transfering the token to your server you could get the token in addition e.g. on each app start.

Comment: You'll typically end up getting the token both in `onNewToken` and in the `onStart` of your app. The latter is mostly needed for your own device, as the token has likely been generated already by the time you deploy an install with `onNewToken` for the first time. Alternatively you can uninstall the app and reinstall it after adding `onNewToken` for the first time, in which case it'll also generate a new token and call `onNewToken`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`onNewToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService#onNewToken(java.lang.String)). What documentation says:

> Called when a new token for the default Firebase project is generated.
>
> This is invoked after app install when a token is first generated, and again if the token changes.

What does it mean is that once the token has been generated this method will not be called until push token has to change.

When your app starts you must get instance of `FirebaseInstanceId` and extract token form it. It will guarantee that you get a valid token.

You should leave the code in your `onNewToken` method as it is and add the code mentioned below to handle cases when the token is already generated:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnSuccessListener { instanceIdResult: InstanceIdResult ->
        val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
        if(currentUser != null){
            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("user").document(currentUser).update("deviceToken", instanceIdResult.token)
        }
    }
```

#### Update: when to use it.

Firstly, you have to understand two things:

- `onNewToken` is called when a **token is absent and has to be generated** (after application installation) OR when the **token has expired and has to be changed**.
- `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnSuccessListener(...)` is NOT generating any tokens! It only returns you currently available, **valid**, safe to use push notification token. There is no use to call it multiple times in your case.

So now you have `onNewToken` in place and ready to process token changes. Good. Leave as is.

Now what you need to handle is a case when a token is already generated, valid and ready to use. `onNewToken` will not be called in that case! Now it's your turn to manually request this token to be returned to you.

Example:

```
class YourActivity: Activity {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        uploadFcmToken()
    }

    private fun uploadFcmToken() {
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnSuccessListener { instanceIdResult: InstanceIdResult ->
            val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
            if(currentUser != null){
                FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                                     .collection("user")
                                     .document(currentUser)
                                     .update("deviceToken", instanceIdResult.token)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to place that code in onStart() everytime the users enter to that activity/fragment ? does this generates a new token each time that user enters to that view ?

Comment: You need to place it in `onCreate` method of your activity. `onStart` will execute it too often but what you actually need is to execute it once when the app has started and each time token is changed (that is handled by `onNewToken`). I'll update my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you added the `onNewToken` implementation *after* FCM had already generated the initial token.

For that specific case (which mostly affects you as the developer, but not your users) you'll want to also get the token in something like the `onStart` of your main activity. Alternatively you can uninstall the app and reinstall it after adding `onNewToken` for the first time, in which case it'll also generate a new token and call `onNewToken`.

So you'll typically end up getting the token both in `onNewToken` and in the `onStart` of your app.

Comment: are those two the right way to do it Frank ? I mean, I need to also provide the generation of the token in onStart ??

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking there. I tried to explain why you may need calls to `getIdToken` in both an activity and in `onNewToken`. If something isn't clear about that, please explain what isn't clear.