# Installing .apk with IntentFilters on Android 12

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging, apk

I want to install the .apk of my Android Application on an Android 12 device. The application contains two IntentFilters which I read might lead to some problems when installing on Android 12. The installations works perfectly fine on Android 10 as well as Android 11.

MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true, Exported = true)]
```

AndroidMaifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="true" />


<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Is there anything I missed that needs to be changed in order to work on Android 12?

Edit:

I changed some parts of the AndroidManifest.xml now, but I still can't get it working. I am a little bit clueless which settings I need to change in order to avoid the error: ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]

FirebaseMessagingService.cs:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]

public override void OnNewToken(string p0)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + p0);
        Task task = SendRegistrationToServer(p0);
        task.Wait();
        token = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name="MyFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
              <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Edit 2:
I can install the app on Android 12 now. Unfortunately another problem occured, when I open the app for the first time the FCM token should be generated and fire the "OnNewToken"-Method. This method is not fired when I use Android 12 but it works on Android 11 and Android 10.

MainActivity.cs

```
[Service(Exported = false)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT", "com.google.firebase.REGISTRATION" })]
public override void OnNewToken(string p0)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + p0);
        Task task = SendRegistrationToServer(p0);
        task.Wait();
        token = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
    }
```

Comment: Can you *try* installing it and post any error you get from logcat? Or is there no A12 emulator yet?

Comment: I set up an emulator for A12 and I get the following error: ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]

Comment: Nice, now google that error! There's a self-answered SO question named exactly like the error, with a solution that seems to make sense ;)

Comment: Installation works now. Unfortunately another problem occured, the OnNewToken is not called in A12 when I first open the app.

Answer (score 0):

Had you tried to uninstall the app from the device and install it again? It seems that the `OnNewToken` method will just call once when the app run on the device at first time.

In addition, you can try to add the following code into the intent filter:

```
"com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"
```

Comment: When I run the app on my emulator device the OnNewToken Method is not called. However, I installed the app on three different physical devices now and the method is called on each one, so it probably is a problem with my A12 emulator device.

Comment: When you uninstall it from the A12 emulator and run it, the OnNewToken Method is still not called?@ForzaJuve

Comment: I have tried a few times and it did not work, but I will try again in a few minutes just to reassure.

Comment: Does it work now?@ForzaJuve

Comment: Firstly, sorry I could not answer earlier and secondly it works when I install the .apk from my webserver on my emulator but it does not work when running the application in debugging mode.

Comment: You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63236185/firebase-onnewtoken-not-refreshing-my-token), according to it, if the method  had been called when you run it first time, it will not been called when you run in debugger.@ForzaJuve